# Firebase deploy error on Travis

Tags: firebase, travis-ci, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I'm trying to deploy to Firebase Hosting using Travis but am getting the following error:

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools
$ firebase --non-interactive deploy --token "${FIREBASE_TOKEN}"
Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:
undefined is not a function
```

That error is not helpful and makes it seem like a bug in `firebase-tools` or I called it in an unexpected way. What do you think might be wrong or what should I try looking into?

My `firebase.json` looks like:

```
{
  "firebase": "myApp",
  "public": "./dist",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "rules": "./rules.bolt"
}
```

`firebase.json` is in the root directory and running the same commands work fine locally.

Here's my full `.travis.yml`:

```
install:
  - npm install
  - bower install
script:
  - gulp
after_success:
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
  - firebase --non-interactive deploy --token "${FIREBASE_TOKEN}"
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
  - bower_components
```

I cleared the cache on Travis and confirmed it is running `firebase-tools` version `2.2.0`.

Comment: I think this is a Bolt error. What happens when you compile your Bolt rules locally?

Comment: Yup you're right. I removed `"rules": "./rules.bolt"` from `firebase.json` and it deployed fine on Travis. I tried adding `npm install -g firebase-bolt` but it still gave the same error. It works fine locally... `firebase-bolt < rules.bolt > rules.json` works correctly. `firebase deploy` seems to deploy my bolt rules correctly when run locally. Thanks for the suggestion :) Definitely the right direction. I'm not sure what the solution is... I can deploy the rules manually so it's not too bad.

Comment: What is your node version? Locally and cor the Travis box that is.

Comment: Ah yep thanks! I guess I haven't updated in awhile and hadn't had any other issues. Locally was `0.12.7`. I didn't specify anything for Travis so it chose `0.10.36`. Added `language: node_js` and `node_js: - "4.1"` to `.travis.yml` and it works great. Feel free to add an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great! I added an answer with a better explanation as well.

Comment: Thanks! That explanation makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use node `0.12` or above.**

While the Firebase CLI and the Bolt compiler both work with node `0.10`+, compiling your Bolt rules with the Firebase CLI requires node `0.12`+.

This is because before node `0.12` there was no way to synchronously call out to an external module, which the Firebase CLI requires to compile Bolt rules.

Work around for those having to use node.10.x - use firebase-bolt directly:

```
$ firebase-bolt rules.bolt  # creates rules.json
```

In firebase.json use: "rules": "./rules.json"

Comment: Work around for those having to use node.10.x - use firebase-bolt directly:

```
$ npm install -g firebase-bolt
$ firebase-bolt rules.bolt  # creates rules.json

In firebase.json use: "rules": "./rules.json"
```

Answer (score 2):

Work around for those having to use node.10.x - use firebase-bolt directly:

```
$ firebase-bolt rules.bolt  # creates rules.json
```

In firebase.json use: "rules": "./rules.json"